# Pop to root then perform segue on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am running on iOS 6.0 storyboard enabled

I have a NavController linked to a TableViewController.
This TableView can segue to AViewController or BViewController.

When I am in A, I want to pop back to the root and perform segue to B with this line :

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
[nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[nav performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToB" sender:self];
```

I checked the storyboard, GoToB do exist and is linked from the TableViewController to BViewController

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<NavMainViewController: 0xb921fa0>) has no segue with identifier 'GoToB''
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segue will be attached to the view controller you pop to, not `nav` which is the container view controller that contains it.  So this would be closer:

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
[nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

UIViewController *rootVC = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[rootVC performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToB" sender:self];
```

But, I think the problem here will be that the pop animation will conflict with the segue.  Doing the pop with ...Animated:NO might fix it, but I think it would be more correct (and more robust for animations) to perform the segue from the rootVC.

rootVC would implement viewDidAppear as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (!self.isBeingPresented && /* any other condition that makes you want this */) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToB" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: In your second example : how can I send a message to the rootVC ? Is there something like a parsable data bound to the viewcontroller instead of using tags ?

Comment: Well I created a variable that I put in a singleton, hope it is a good way to parse data.

Comment: Is the problem that the rootVC doesn't know whether it should do the segue?  You can always get the instance by looking at the first vc in the navigation controller's viewControllers stack.  Maybe give it a property?  But usually when you find yourself needing to do this (or a singleton) it means your model is missing some state that the vcs ought to be checking.