# After using presentViewController existing segues can't be found

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am returning to my login view using the code below. The view loads correctly and everything looks fine. All buttons work etc.

```
JALoginViewController *loginVC = [[JALoginViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];

navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

However, if a user tries to log in again, the segue that takes them to the next scene can't be found.

I'm using performSegueWithIdentifier if the users login credentials are correct, like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
```

This is the error I receive:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<JALoginViewController: 0x8d614b0>) has no segue with identifier 'loginSegue''
```

I've done lots of searching on Google and through the docs for the solution to this, the closet I've got (at least I think) is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417370/pop-to-root-then-perform-segue-on-iphone). The explain and solution sound like they could be correct and relevant, but I can't put them into practice.

Documents I've read and tried:

[initWithRootViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[popToRootViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - The current root view controller is for a tab bar - not the login scene I need so as far as I'm aware I can't use this.

[popViewControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[pushViewControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - This works to an effect, I don't think it is the correct way though. I don't want there to be navigation bar and I don't want my tab bar to appear when the user returns to the login scene.

I've tried various methods with limited / no effect. At this stage any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if I haven't provided enough information.

Thanks

JA

Edit - Zoomed out image of storyboard

![Zoomed out image of Storyboard][1]

Comment: You asked whether you might be able to provide more information: A zoomed-out version of your storyboard (shift-command-4 to take a snapshot) might be helpful.

Comment: As requested I've added a zoomed out image. The right boxes highlight where I am and I where I want to return to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of the screen snapshot of the revised question, from your rightmost red-highlighted scene, you should be able to:

```
[self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and you'll be back at that initial screen (I'm assuming you did modal segue from initial screen to your tab bar controller).

---

Original answer:

If you want to manually push to a view controller, rather than creating it via `alloc`/`init`, you should use

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginsSceneStoryboardIdHere"];
```

or, if that view controller was the "initial" scene (the one with the simple arrow coming in from the left), you could use

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

And you shouldn't be manually creating the navigation controller, either. If the `loginVC` needs a navigation controller, you should embed that scene in a navigation controller right in the Interface Builder, then give that new navigation controller its own unique storyboard identifier, and then you can

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navControllerSceneStoryboardIdHere"];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

I must confess that I'm worried by this whole "return to login via pushViewController" construct. I assume you know that you're not "returning" to it, but creating a new copy of it. If you push/modal from A to B and then B to C and then C to A, you're holding 4 views and their controllers in memory, two copies of A and one of B and one of C (which is, obviously, not good). I just wanted to make sure you don't have a circular set of segues and/or push/presentViewController references.

If the login is the initial scene in your app and if you've been doing only push segues (no modal segues along the way), you can do a:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

That will take you to the top level view controller, and it will pop off and release all of the intervening scenes.

If you're using iOS 6, you can avail yourself of the unwind segue, which can achieve the same functionality, but it doesn't care whether the preceding segues were pushes or modals.

There are lots of ways of skinning the cat, but generally doing a new `presentViewController` to the first scene in your storyboard is a very bad idea.

Comment: Rob, thanks very much for taking the time to help me with this. You're absolutely right there will be some views retained in memory so I should definitely make some adjustments. Unfortunately I can't use popToRootViewController in this scene, I am using that method else where and it works fine, however this scene has it's own navigation controller, embedded in IB and popToRootViewController takes me back here. Apologies if I'm going round the houses here, I'm really quite new to iOS programming.

Comment: @Gr3mlin Understood. It strikes me, though, worthwhile to solve this properly rather than just hoping that the user doesn't repeat this process too many times and cause your app to crash due to running out of memory. While iPhone 5 has 1gb of RAM, the 4 only has 512mb and the 3GS has 256mb of RAM, so one has to be judicious in the use of memory (we get lulled into a sense of false security when testing on simulator or newer devices). If targeting iOS 6 and higher, only, you can use unwind segue. If not, the specifics of the solution will be dependent upon your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks Rob, unfortunately I'm supporting >= iOS 5, so using unwing segue isn't an option for me. :-(

Comment: Would it be bad practice to use your code above, but use popToRootViewController, in the viewWillAppear method of the login scene's navigation controller? I suppose all of the old view's attached to  the last navigation controller will still be stored in memory, leaving only the views attached to the new controller free to be taken off the stack?

Comment: @Gr3mlin From your rightmost red-highlighted scene, you can just do `[self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and you'll be back at that initial screen (I'm assuming you did modal segue from initial screen to your tab bar controller). In answer to your question about the login scene's `viewWillAppear`, while I appreciate the creativity there, no I don't think that works.

Comment: Rob, you are the man! Can't begin to tell you how much I appreciate all of the help you have given me. This is now working perfectly.